# How to encrypt full routes in ruby on rails at Application level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, routes, rubygems

I want to encrypt routes in ruby on rails application through routes file.

```
Sample URL: http://localhost:3000/users or http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit

Encrypted URL: http://localhost:3000/dshfkhjkbkbjkdfjkfdhk or http://localhost:3000/dshfkhjkbkbjkdfjkfdhk/dskjfs/hdfkjdf
```

It's possible to encrypt using any gem.
How to manage all routes encryption at the Application level

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't. All you can do is implement your own router, and map all encrypted paths to a single controller and let that controller call your router.

```rb
# config/routes.rb
match '*path', to: 'encrypted#index', via: :all
```

```rb
class EncryptedController < ApplicationController
  def index
    path = params[:path]
    decrypted_path = path.split('/').map{|part| decrypt(part)}.join('/')
    MyRouter.dispatch(request.method, decrypted_path, request)
  end
end
```

```rb
module MyRouter
  def self.dispatch(request_method, path, request)
    # Your own dispatching logic here.
    # Note that this method should return a Rack-compatible response.
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please share one example? I don't know how to return a Rack-compatible response.

Comment: The simplest format is `[status_code, response_headers, response_body_parts]`, like `[200, {'content-type' => 'text/plain'}, ['hello world']]`.

Comment: Can I generate the encrypted paths dynamically? like using encryption method

Comment: No. Furthermore, you don't have access to any of the URL helpers Rails provided when you go for this approach. By the way, why do you want to encrypt the paths?

Comment: due to security reasons, I want to encrypt the URL.

Comment: So, you don't want the end-user see the clear URL? Is there any sensitive data embedded in URL? If you encrypt the URLs, you'll lose all possibilities of URL-related SEO. If I were you, I'd just go for HTTPS.

Comment: using rails routes URL hackers can easily find the URL pattern. we have secured the authentication module in the Rails application but we don't want to take any risk so if we can encrypt the URL at the application level then we want to secure the URL more. can we encrypt only id data in URL Without saving data?

Comment: If you require authentication to access the routes, "encrypting" them doesn't really add anything -- there will be a 403 response for unauthenticated access no matter what the route is. If you want to obfuscate your routes consider using uuids for models instead of integers.